# Why doesn't let me to remove the address field?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have 1 field radio button with 2 values: delivery & pickup.

I would like if someone choose pickup, to remove all unnecessary fields: address1, address2, city, zipcode, country, company ( remove required too ).

If the delivery value checked, to works as is it.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wps_select_checkout_field_process');
 function wps_select_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

 if ($_POST['delivery'] == "Ridicare")

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
unset($fields['billing']['address-line1']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);


return $fields;
}

 }
```

On validation, i get an error from address field...

Comment: This requires something more complex with jQuery…

Answer (score 0):

"woocommerce_checkout_fields" hook remove the fields on checkout page but you place the order then woocomerce check all filed validation.

So, it will be easier to disable post code and state validation with it.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'misha_disable_address_fields_validation' );

function misha_disable_address_fields_validation( $address_fields_array ) {

```
unset( $address_fields_array['state']['validate']);
unset( $address_fields_array['postcode']['validate']);
// you can also hook first_name and last_name, company, country, city, address_1 and address_2

return $address_fields_array;
```

}

https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/checkout-fields.html

Comment: It works only without if...  if ($_POST['delivery'] == "Ridicare")

Comment: Can you give me URL?